# How to convert %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82 to Unicode in JS

Tags: javascript, web, unicode, encoding, symbols

The main core of question is — I did not know what's the name of this type of string.
I am getting output function strings in this format %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82. I don't know what type of code is this. Tell me please how to convert it to Unicode in JavaScript.
Actually this string is "Привет". Thank you.

Comment: I used decodeURI() function, works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

> The decodeURIComponent() function decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or by a similar routine.

```js
var decodedStr = decodeURIComponent('%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82')
console.log(decodedStr);
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I am using decodeURI() now, works well.